# ¿Por qué me da el error Notice: Undefined index PHP?

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

**ERROR PARA SUBIR ARCHIVOS**
//soy novato :c

Notice: Undefined index: archivofls in C:\xampp\htdocs\tarea\subir-archivo.php on line 2

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\tarea\subir-archivo.php on line 3

Este es el index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Subir Archivos</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h2>Subir Archivo</h2>
<br>
<hr>
<form name="enviar_achivo_frm" method="post" action="subir-archivo.php"enctype="multipart/from-data">
<input type="file" name="archivofls"/>
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="subir_fls" value="Subir Archivo"/>
</form>
<br>
<hr>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

y este es el subir-archivo.php

```
<?php 
foreach ($archivo as $clave => $valor) {
    echo "Propiedad: $clave --- valor: $valor<br/>";
}

?>
```

Me podrían ayudar :c

Comment: bueno la parte del html esta bien pero lo que hiciste con el PHP humm no es asi. para acceder a lo que envias en un submit tipo multipart tendras que utilizar la variable global $_FILES esta funciona como un $_POST por lo que tu archivo lo podras acceder desde $_FILES['archivofls'], ya el resto te recomiento que busques en el sitio oficial, move_uploaded_file> http://php.net/manual/es/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: ¿Qué es `$archivo` en subir-archivo.php? Aparte, tienes un fallo tipográfico en `enctype="multipart/from-data"` debería ser `enctype="multipart/form-data"` (aunque no sé si eso te causará problemas)